# Determining the lag order of an autoregression model

Tags: time-series, model-selection, aic, autoregressive, lags

I'm trying to fit my time series data, which have 37 entries, with an autoregression model. The data look like:
[image]

I just loop over 1 to 18, each of which is used as the order of AR model. A plot of the relationship of AIC and order is shown below[image].

I'm curious about the trend of AIC from order 14 to 18, the sudden decrease following the increase from order 4 to 14. Is it overfitting? To choose the best order, shall I use 4 or 18?

The autocorrelation function is like:
[image]

And the partial autocorrelation function is like:
[image]

Comment: The length of the series is only 37? Almost surely overfitting.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes, only 37. But shouldn't AIC be already penalizing overfitting? So I should choose 4 instead of 18?

Comment: It's of course difficult to decide without knowing more about the data than you have told us, but autoregressive models are seldom used with so many lags. Are you sure the series is stationary? Or is the series from some domain where long range dependence can be expected? You should tell us more show a plot of the series, show the autocorrelation function ... All that said, AIC should not be taken as more than arough guide. I have seen examples where more parameters betters the AIC, without I being able to understand why. No better predictions,  no better fit. Is your 18-lag fit really better?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you for the explanation. I'm new to this area and read a paper in which AIC was used to tell the order of AR model. I don't even know how to turn a non-stationary time series to a stationary one... I attached the ACF and PACF to the question. I guess I need to do some non-stationary study first.

Comment: What does your actual time series look like?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I just added the plot of raw time series to the question. The first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AIC should be calculated from residuals using models that control for intervention administration, otherwise the intervention effects are taken to be Gaussian noise, underestimating the actual model's autoregressive effect and thus miscalculates the model parameters which leads directly to an incorrect error sum of squares and ultimately an incorrect AIC. Most SE responders do not point out this assumption when they promote the free auto.arima tool which I think is a serious error of omission.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking about what is an intervention...Observation?

Comment: An intervention is either a pulse . level shift , time trend or seasonal pulse .. also known as outlers   http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html