# What high order lags mean in the VAR/SVAR?

Tags: time-series, lags

I am new to VAR/SVAR and microeconomics.

I learn (from [here](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v92/malinsky18a/malinsky18a.pdf)) that a k-dimension p-order SVAR can be written as $X_{i,t}=f_i(X_t^{-i},X_{t-1},...,X_{t-p},\epsilon_{i,t})$, where $i$ indexes the number of variable, $t$ indexes time, $X_t=\{ X_{1,t}, X_{2,t}, ..., X_{k,t}\}$ and $X_t^{-i}=X_t\setminus \{ X_{i,t} \}$.

I know VAR/SVAR are discrete-time models for a continuous-time process (such as microeconomics).

However, I am confused about what the order (i.e. $p=1,2,...$) of lags means. I list two of my guesses below:

##### Guess 1

Do they stand for the speed of influence? Can I interpret that an order-2 lag represents a slower influence than an order-1 lag?

For example, if $X_{0,t}$ have an order-1 lag from $X_{1,t-1}$ and an order-2 lag from $X_{2,t-2}$. Does this mean the influence from $X_1$ to $X_0$ is faster than that from $X_2$ to $X_0$?

##### Guess 2

Or maybe the order of lags means the order of Markov? like an order-1 lag means a MDP (Markov Decision Process)? If this is the case, I think an higher order lag can not show without an lower order lag, right?

I find some related [answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348410/determining-the-lag-order-of-an-autoregression-model). But they are about how to decide the optimal order of lags.

I hope to learn the detailed literature, so please cite some papers if you can.

Comment: Hi @Mingzhou. In some sense, a lag is about speed. A lagged process that has an effect within 1 period, rather than 2 periods, is faster. This certainly matters in terms of economic policy (fiscal policy may affect investment that a slower rate than monetary policy, potentially). But when sticking with the pure econometric specification, we're predominantly looking to: (1) ensure that lags convey information about the time series process through time, and that (2) enough lags are included to ensure that the errors become white noise (this is the intention of optimal lag-length determination).

Comment: @EB3112. Hi, I edited my questions before reading your comments. So I believe the order of lags means the order of Markov? like an order-1 lag means a MDP (Markov Decision Process)? If this is the case, I think a higher order lag can not show without a lower order lag, right?

Comment: Hi again @ Mingzhou. If you're new to the world of time series analysis, I would very much recommend looking at the building blocks of VARs such as AR processes, stationarity, unit root tests, lag-length determination, endogeneity, and impulse response functions. VARs require an understanding of all of these things in the context of economics. A decent introductory book here is Brooks, Introduction to Financial Econometrics. If by comparison, you'd like to just go straight for a course on VARs, then the IMF course is good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCinpWc2nXA&t=3s

Comment: Indeed, $p$ is about the lags. With monthly data, we for example often observe empirically that lag 12 matters due to seasonal effects. It is indeed relatively uncommon to drop intermediate lags, although technically, you can do it without further issues. Also, that is what "SARMA", i.e. seasonal ARMA models basically do.